# Las pruebas unitarias fallan al llamar el método fail

Tags: java, pruebas-unitarias, junit

Desarrollé un juego en Java y le tengo que hacer pruebas unitarias. Las hago y me sale error en las pruebas pero no entiendo por qué, si el juego funciona como se esperaba. El código de pruebas es el siguiente:

```
package Frames;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Daniel
 */
public class ConstelacionTest {

    public ConstelacionTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of Mensaje method, of class Constelacion.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMensaje() {
        System.out.println("Mensaje");
        Constelacion instance = new Constelacion();
        instance.Mensaje();
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of CleanBoton method, of class Constelacion.
     */
    @Test
    public void testCleanBoton() {
        System.out.println("CleanBoton");
        Constelacion instance = new Constelacion();
        instance.CleanBoton();
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

    /**
     * Test of main method, of class Constelacion.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        System.out.println("main");
        String[] args = null;
        Constelacion.main(args);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }

}
```

Y al ejecutarlo me sale este error en las pruebas. ¿Alguien me podría decir por qué está erróneo el resultado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas indicando un error en todos los metodos con `fail`. El propio comentario en ingles te pone que lo elimines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facil, elimina los fail de los metodos como te indican los comentarios del codigo

```
package Frames;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Daniel
 */
public class ConstelacionTest {

    public ConstelacionTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of Mensaje method, of class Constelacion.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMensaje() {
        System.out.println("Mensaje");
        Constelacion instance = new Constelacion();
        instance.Mensaje();
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    }

    /**
     * Test of CleanBoton method, of class Constelacion.
     */
    @Test
    public void testCleanBoton() {
        System.out.println("CleanBoton");
        Constelacion instance = new Constelacion();
        instance.CleanBoton();
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    }

    /**
     * Test of main method, of class Constelacion.
     */
    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        System.out.println("main");
        String[] args = null;
        Constelacion.main(args);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    }

}
```